# Jquery validation plugin + php action not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

im using the jQuery Validate plugin but its not firing for me, I have an action on my php form which lets me handle images and also send the rest of the info to a db. here is my code any help would be appreciated. I got it to stop submission so its not redirecting at all. I need it to check values and if its all good then fire the action.

```
 <form name="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" id="newProject"/>
            <div class="inputs">
              <p>
                <span class="required"></span>
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title:" value="Title of Image"  />
                <small>This is the <strong>Title</strong> of the image.</small>
              </p>
              <p>
                <span class="required"></span>
                <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description:" value="Description"  />
                <small><strong>Description</strong> is shortened on main pages but will be fully displayed on the <strong>Single page</strong></small>
              </p>
              <p><span class="required"></span>
                <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="category" value="1">Landscape<br />
              <span class="required"></span>
                <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="category" value="2">Portrait<br />
              <span class="required"></span>
                <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="category" value="3">Monochrome<br />
                <small></small>
              </p>
              <p><span class="required"></span>
              <input class="uploadFile" type="file" size="32" name="my_field" value=""  />
              <input type="hidden" name="action" value="image" /></p>
              <div class="actions">                     
              <p><button class="button" id="update_profile" value="upload">Upload</button></p>
              </div>
            </div>
         </form>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#newProject" ).validate({
rules: {
       title: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 4,
               maxlength: 20
       }
       description: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 20,
               maxlength: 500
       }
},
       messages: {
            title: {
               required: "Enter a title",
               minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
               maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
            }
            description: {
               required: "Enter a description",
               minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
               maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
            }
       }
   });
});  
</script> 

<script>
$(function(){


$("#newProject").on('submit', function(e){
    var isvalidate=$("#newProject").valid();
    if(isvalidate)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(getvalues("newProject"));
    }
});

});

function getvalues(f)
{
    var form=$("#"+f);
    var str='';
    $("input:not('input:submit')", form).each(function(i){
        str+='\n'+$(this).prop('title')+': '+$(this).val();
    });
    return str;
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(function() {
   $( "#newProject" ).validate({
rules: {
       title: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 4,
               maxlength: 20
       },
       description: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 20,
               maxlength: 500
       }
},
       messages: {
            title: {
               required: "Enter a title",
               minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
               maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
            },
            description: {
               required: "Enter a description",
               minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
               maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
            }
       }
   });
});
```

you need to add comma after every rule and message

Comment: Nop, nothing it goes straight to the promp with all values no validation whatsoever

Comment: did you replace your code with the code above? It does validation I checked it on my machine.

Comment: Oh wait !! it worked now... awesome, the only step is how do i make it submit to the action instead of the prompt

Comment: lol just needed to remove the prompt to submit it.. Thank you for the help